# I'd like to disaggregate a list of strings to split on "/" and " and " to a list of unique strings

Tags: python, flatten

I have a list like ["Alex Smith", "John Jones/John Jones and Anna Conner", "James O'Brien"].  I'd like to convert it to a list of individual unique individuals: ["Alex Smith", "John Jones", "Anna Conner", "James O'Brien"].  I can use list(set(vector)) to get the uniqueness that I want, but the splitting is giving me a headache.

I looked at [Flattening a shallow list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python) and it looked good, but it disggregated down to the indivual letters rather than the combination of first and last names.

Comment: Please show some code of what you have tried so far and better or more examples of input and desired output. The problem you describe is still too broad and ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks to @TigerhawkT3.  His suggestion gave me just what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Pick a delimiter, join on that delimiter, convert all delimiters to that one, split on that delimiter, then use `set()` as you were planning on to remove the duplicates:

```
l = ["Alex Smith", "John Jones/John Jones and Anna Conner", "James O'Brien"]
new_set = set('/'.join(l).replace(' and ', '/').split('/'))
```

Result:

```
>>> new_set
{"James O'Brien", 'Alex Smith', 'John Jones', 'Anna Conner'}
```